# CodenameOne How to use resource file of GUI Designer

Tags: resources, codenameone, designer

I just created a small test app using CodenameOne without the GuiDesigner. Now I tried to create a UI with the Designer using IntelliJ Idea IDE.
I did the following:

- Right-click on `src` package: New -> Codename One Container.
  This results in a `MyContainer.java` file.
- Right-click on MyContainer.java: New -> Codename One -> Codename One Designer. This results in the GUI Builder window.
- I created a blank container and some buttons and added a multi image.

**Now first problem:** Where to store this file? I stored it in the src directory as `MyContainer.res` .

**Now second problem:** How to use this res file? How to load it? How to get the multi image out of it? What is the res directory for? Should it be placed there?

My code looks as follows:

```
public class MyApplication  {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }

        Form form = new Form("Main", new BorderLayout());
        // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        // ----> Here I want the created container to be inserted into the form
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if (current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog) current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

I inserted a comment in the code above where I want to load the UI of the res file.

I tried many ways. One was the following but I always get an `InvcationTargetException` executing the second line:

```
UIBuilder uib = new UIBuilder();
Container cnt = uib.createContainer("MyContainer", "Container");
```

I tried it with a slash in front of the first parameter and I changed the parameters but nothing worked.

Do I have to start initially with a res file to load subsequent res files? If yes, how to start with a res file?

Please help me after trying 6 hours at this Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

The designer includes [the old GUI builder and not the new one](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-the-new-gui-builder.html). I would suggest avoiding it as we are putting all of our resources into the new GUI builder which has a more familiar approach to GUI design using XML and one source file == one form.

The old GUI builder only makes sense for projects created explicitly for it as then we generate all the stub code automatically.

Comment: I just tried the new GUI builder and have some technical problems with it. It seems the refresh does not work properly. If I change e.g. the layout to border layout it's not displayed immediately in the component tree. After adding a new component to the tree is updated. One single time the UI didn't response anymore and I had to kill it (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04). But the generated Java and GUI files seem to work.

Comment: But a question concerning adding images to be used in the new GUI Builder: Do I have to use the old GUI Designer to add an image to the project? I cannot see any menu item in the new GUI Builder providing functionality to add an image. In the support video the old GUI Designer is used to add images to the res file.

Comment: We have a major plugin update coming this weekend that should overhaul the GUI builder significantly and hopefully resolve the issues. If it doesn't please file issues in the issue tracker with ways to reproduce http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/ images are placed within the res file which is edited using the designer (which also designs the themes). The old tool was a mix of multiple tools: localization, theming, resource management etc. We are breaking it up to smaller tools one piece at a time starting with the GUI building capabilities. The other tools are still there...